# Turn nested arrays into objects

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have been unable to figure out how to turn a nested array such as:

```
var array = [
    [['firstName', 'Henry'], ['codeName', 'Etta'], ['email', 'henry@hardcore.net'], ['weight', 180], ['occupation', 'repo']],
    [['firstName', 'Bruce'], ['codeName', 'DK'], ['email', 'IamB@man.com'],
 ['weight', 200], ['occupation', 'enforcement']]
];
```

into an object such as

```
var array = [
    {firstName: 'Henry', codeName: 'Etta', email: 'henry@hardcore.net', weight: 180, occupation: 'repo'},
    {firstName: 'Bruce', codeName: 'DK', email: 'IamB@man.com', weight: 200, occupation: 'enforcement'}
];
```

Below is what I've come up with so far, but it is clearly not producing the results I need.

```
function arrIntoObject(array) {
  var obj = {};

  array.map(function(a) {
    a.map(function(e) {
      obj[e[0]] = e[1];  
    });
  });
  return obj;
}
```

This seems like a question that would have been asked by now, but after hours I haven't been able to find a similar question, so I would appreciate any help or guidance here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.map()` with `.reduce()`, like so:

```js
var array = [
    [['firstName', 'Henry'], ['codeName', 'Etta'], ['email', 'henry@hardcore.net'], ['weight', 180], ['occupation', 'repo']],
    [['firstName', 'Bruce'], ['codeName', 'DK'], ['email', 'IamB@man.com'],
 ['weight', 200], ['occupation', 'enforcement']]
];

var objs = array.map(function (arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (res, curr) {
    var [key, value] = curr;
    res[key] = value;
    return res;
  }, {});
});

console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just reduce the arrays into an object

```js
var array = [
  [['firstName', 'Henry'],['codeName', 'Etta'],['email', 'henry@hardcore.net'],['weight', 180],['occupation', 'repo']],
  [['firstName', 'Bruce'],['codeName', 'DK'],['email', 'IamB@man.com'],['weight', 200],['occupation', 'enforcement']]
];

var obj = array.map( arr => arr.reduce( (acc, curr) => { 
    acc[ curr[0] ] = curr[1]; return acc;
}, {}));


console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0; max-height: 100%!important}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` with spread syntax `...` and `Object.assign()`

```js
var array = [[['firstName', 'Henry'], ['codeName', 'Etta'], ['email', 'henry@hardcore.net'], ['weight', 180], ['occupation', 'repo']],[['firstName', 'Bruce'], ['codeName', 'DK'], ['email', 'IamB@man.com'],['weight', 200], ['occupation', 'enforcement']]];

var result = array.map(e => Object.assign({}, ...e.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))))
console.log(result)
```

You can also use `map()` and then `reduce()` with `Object.assign()`

```js
var array = [[['firstName', 'Henry'], ['codeName', 'Etta'], ['email', 'henry@hardcore.net'], ['weight', 180], ['occupation', 'repo']],[['firstName', 'Bruce'], ['codeName', 'DK'], ['email', 'IamB@man.com'],['weight', 200], ['occupation', 'enforcement']]];

var result = array.map(e => e.reduce((r, [k, v]) => Object.assign(r, {[k]: v}),{}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` method, it permits to reduce an array to a single variable, in this case an object.
For more informations give a look to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)

```js
var initialArray = [
    [['firstName', 'Henry'], ['codeName', 'Etta'], ['email', 'henry@hardcore.net'], ['weight', 180], ['occupation', 'repo']],
    [['firstName', 'Bruce'], ['codeName', 'DK'], ['email', 'IamB@man.com'],
 ['weight', 200], ['occupation', 'enforcement']]
];

function arrayToObject(a) {
  return a.reduce(function (obj, keyValue) {
    obj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

var finalArray = initialArray.map(arrayToObject);

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this simple logic might helps.

```js
var array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Henry'],
    ['codeName', 'Etta'],
    ['email', 'henry@hardcore.net'],
    ['weight', 180],
    ['occupation', 'repo']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Bruce'],
    ['codeName', 'DK'],
    ['email', 'IamB@man.com'],
    ['weight', 200],
    ['occupation', 'enforcement']
  ]
];

var output = [];
array.forEach(function(arr1) {
  output.push({});
  arr1.forEach(function(arr2) {
    output[output.length - 1][arr2[0]] = arr2[1];
  })
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.map(val => val.reduce(function(obj, prop) {
  obj[prop[0]] = prop[1];
  return obj;
}, {}));
```